# How to read awk from one file and compare it with awk from another file

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, etcpasswd

The script I have is outputting $1 the most often logged users in the past $2 days

```
#var[$i]=$(awk -F: '{print $5}' /etc/passwd);
last -s -$2days | awk '{users[$1]++} END{for(i in users){print users[i], i}}' | sort -r | head -$1 | awk '{print $2 " -- " $1}';
```

so the output is following:

```
username -- (amount of logins)
```

But I'm trying to get an output with first and last name from /etc/passwd so it's:

```
first and last name, username -- (amount of logins)
```

But every idea I try to come up with doesn't seem to work for me. I tried looping the awk with /etc/passwd and then using -v in another awk or trying to get the output of 2nd awk into an array and then comparing it with /etc/passwd but I couldn't make either work.
Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should let you start:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{name[$1]=$5;next} {u[$1]++}
    END{for(x in u)printf "%s, %s -- %d\n", name[x],x,u[x]} ' FS=":" /etc/passwd FS=" " <(last)
```

- this will output all `first and last name, username -- (amount of logins)` from `last` command
- you may want to adjust the `last` command by adding some required options
- the `sort` and `head` are omitted, I believe you can handle it

Comment: Thank you very much, I adjusted it so it works with the parameters I wanted it to give.

I'm not sure what does "next" do (in the first part of the awk), could you clarify?

Comment: @Flamenco you're welcome. when `next` was hit, awk will stop further processing and pick the next record (input line). Here we used `next` to make sure that awk will only apply the `NR==FNR{...}` on the first input file.